# jquery ajax not passing data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

On the front-side i am recording user selections:

```
 var type = $.cookie('liste-voyage-type');  
 var code=  $.cookie('liste-voyage-code');
```

i then pass these variables to the server

```
$.ajax({
   url: '../listing-voyage-produit.php', 
   type: "GET",     
   data :  ({type: type,code :code}),
  success: function(data){
         alert('data:'+data);
  }
});
```

i want to dynamically modify the variables

```
  $type and $code
```

at the back end which are used for a sql request that display products on the page

i miss some elements of understanding:

```
  alert('type:'+type);    => type:2

  alert('code'+code);    => code:Z3\_P95\_

  the success: alert('data:'+data);    =>  data:
```

the callback function is triggered but the alert(data) does not display anything

how can i play with datatype, json, or eval() to make it working , converting the string variales var type and code to json and ultimately modify the variables on the server side to :

```
  echo $type;

  echo $code;
```

Comment: if you are not retrieving any data in success, you wont be able to see any data... make sure your success callback return some data...

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to check the response body?

Comment: what about server side code? What did you do there to get the result?

Comment: in this function `function(data){` `data` will be the response from server side `listing-voyage-produit.php`.

Comment: does the javascript give you an error upon .get() request and what exactly are you trying to do with the backend?

Comment: @patel.milanb the success callback function do not return anything. if i add datatype:'json' it returns null

Answer (score 2):

**your code missing dataType**

```
$.ajax({
   url: '../listing-voyage-produit.php', 
   type: "GET",     
   data :  {type:type,code:code},
   dataType:"json",
  success: function(data){
         alert('data:'+data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not wrap your data with parenthesis ()

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
...
data :  {type: type,code :code},
dataType: 'json',
...
```

**PHP**

```
// decode data sent
$json = json_decode($_POST['data']);

// encode data to send back
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: this won't solve OP issue but that's right than here parenthesis  are useless (but still valid)

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? pass the data to a php file and return the same exact data back?